# WCF Configuration editor (no service)

Tags: wcf

I am trying to follow this tutorial

[Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648360.aspx)

but I am hitting a problem right from the start.

I create the new website and I give it the address. I can see the files in my inepub folder. I can browse to the service using "localhost//WCFService//Service.svc".

So all good.

When I right click on the webconfig file and choose the Edit WCF Configuration the window opens but there is no service registered.

[image]

So I tried to create a new service using the Create a New Service wizard and it asks for a Service Type.

[image]

My service does not appear as a type ... in fact there are no service type.

So if I follow the wizard to the end just entering names it warns me that the type maybe invalid and there seems to be no connection between the config and my service.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Service.svc is not the service. The wizard is looikng for a `ServiceContact`. Check [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlyND7b2-YA)

Comment: Thanks man. It sorted me out. Great little tutorial. I managed to add my existing service and use the configuration tool

Comment: In the video they delete IService.cs and Service.cs. Does anyone know why the service configuration editor doesn't see the build in service (i.e. those two classes)?

Comment: This tool is doesnt find anything, even marked with the correct attributes.